# авторизация на C# и MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Имеется следующий код:

```
string Connect = "server=localhost;uid=admin;password=admin;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=test_database";
string CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM login WHERE login = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND password = '" + textBox2.Text + "' LIMIT 1";
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
myConnection.Open();**//я не понял что тут писать?**
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();**//и тут тоже?**
MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
{
    this.Hide();
    disp dp = new disp();
    dp.Show();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность введенных данных!");
}
```

Ошибка на строке: `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unknown column 'password' in
>   'where clause'"

Как это исправить?

Comment: В методе `Open` писать ничего не нужно, он просто открывает соединение. А метод [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) выполняет инструкцию `SQL` для установленного соединения и возвращает количество задействованных в инструкции строк. Не совсем понятно, в чем ваш вопрос.

Comment: Я попробовал но VS выдаёт ошибку и указывает на myConnection.Open();

Comment: он при запуске не ругается и толко во время проверки логина и пароля

Comment: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unknown column 'password' in 'where clause'" ошибка на myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на ваш `SQL`:

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) 
FROM 
    login 
WHERE 
    login = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND 
    password = '" + textBox2.Text + "' 
LIMIT 1
```

Выбрать количество из таблицы `login` где поле(колонка) `login` равна тексту из  `textBox1.Text` и поле(колонка) `password` равна тексту из `textBox2.Text`.

Удостоверьтесь в том, что имя таблицы `login` правильное и она действительно существует. А также и имена столбцов `login` и `password` тоже верны и эти столбцы есть в указанной таблице.

Ошибка:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unknown column 'password' in
>   'where clause'"

говорит о том, что указанная колонка `password` отсутствует в целевой таблице, в вашем случае в таблице `login`. Проверьте внимательно таблицу `login`, есть ли там столбец `password`, может быть там указано имя с одной буквой `s` вот так: `pasword`.

Comment: А может быть так что string не видет базу данных: string Connect = "server=localhost; поскольку я исползую openserver и надо ли писать IP ???

Comment: @beginneroot, текст ошибки указывает на конкретную проблему. Проверьте таблицу `login`, есть ли там столбец `password`, может быть там указано имя с одной буквой `s` вот так: `pasword`

Comment: вы били абсолютно правы я пропустил одну букву в password, написал: passwrd! Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @beginneroot Если ответ помог решить вашу проблему, то вы можете отметить его как ‘Правильный’, галочка напротив ответа.